# in C what is the meaning of this declaration: int *(*table())[30];

Tags: c

```
int *(*table())[30];
```

I cannot find a solution anywhere.
What is the *table(), can it be a function or array?

Can you please tell me what that means?

Comment: [declare table as function returning pointer to array 30 of pointer to int](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com?q=int+*(*table())[30]%3B)

Comment: cdecl is your friend. `cdecl> explain int *(*table())[30]`  
`declare table as function returning pointer to array 30 of pointer to int`

Comment: Please refer to spiral/clockwise rule http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: @user1820451 If any of the answers below has solved your problem, do mark any one as accepted. Read more about this here: [stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 5):

You can decode this from the inside out:

```
int *(*table())[30];
```

The innermost binding is`table()`, which is a function with unspecified arguments.  The next level is `*table()`, so `table` is returning a pointer to something.  The next level is `(*table())[30]`, so it's returning a pointer to a 30-length array of something.  The next level is `*(table())[30]`, so it's returning a pointer to a 30-length array of pointers to something.  The final level adds the type specifier, `int *(*table())[30]`.

So `table` is a function (with unspecified arguments) that returns a pointer to a 30-length array of pointers to `int`.

Comment: Does it go to the 30th place in an array of pointers of ints or returning a pointer of array with length of 30?

Comment: @DeBanana Since it's a declarator, the 30 is an array length, not an index.

Answer (score 3):

Reading of such constructs is much easier if you replace parts of the declaration that can be replaced, with a substitute name. Let's say `f` is `table()`, which is a function taking unspecified number of arguments, and `t` is the type `int*`.

Then the declaration becomes:

```
t(*f)[30];
```

which is obviously a pointer to an array of 30 elements of `t`.

Replace `f`, and we get a function taking unspecified number of arguments, and returning a pointer to an array of 30 elements of t:

```
t(*table())[30];
```

Replace `t` and we get a function taking unspecified number of arguments, and returning a pointer to an array of 30 elements of pointer to int:

```
int*(*table())[30];
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
int *(*table())[30];
```

declares that "table is a function returning a pointer to an array of 30 pointers to int."

There are myriad good articles on how to read C type declarations. [Here is one of them.](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html)

To summarize:

**The rules:**

1. There is a type name on the left. Call that $typename.
2. There is an identifier somewhere towards the right, possibly surrounded by `[]` and `()` and `*`. Call that $identifier.

Your declaration will be templated like: `$identifier` is a ... `$typename`.

3. Start with "$identifier is a(n)".
4. If you can go right, by consuming a `[...]` or a `(...)`, then add that to your declaration. The `[...]` is a (possibly-empty) array declaration, written "array (of ...)"; while the `(...)` is a (possibly-empty) function declaration, written "function returning" or "function taking (...) returning".
5. If you cannot go right, because you reach a semicolon, or comma, or a closing parenthesis, then you must go left. Go left, consuming either the $typename if you are at the end of the process, or consuming a pointer declaration (`*`, written "pointer(s) to") or consuming an opening parenthesis. After consuming any of these, except the $typename, try to go right again.

   Remember: Go right if you can, go left if you must.

**Your question, revisited**

With that in mind, let's look again:

```
int *(*table())[30];
```

Step by step:

1. $typename = "int"
2. $identifier = "table";
3. Start with "$identifier is a(n)": "table is a(n)" `${typename} *(*${declaration}())[30];`
4. Go right: "... function returning" `${typename} *(* ${declaration} )[30];`
5. Go right: fails, because of `)`
6. Go left: "... pointer(s) to" `${typename} * ${declaration} [30];`
7. Go right: "... an array of 30" `${typename} * ${declaration};`
8. Go right: fails, because of `;`  `${typename} * ${declaration}`
9. Go left: "... pointer(s) to" `${typename} ${declaration}`
10. Go right: fails.
11. Go left: "int"

Write that all in order, and you get:

> table is a(n) function returning pointer(s) to an array of 30 pointer(s) to int

Clean up the sentence by removing (s) where not needed, and replacing single pointer with "a pointer":

> table is a function returning a pointer to an array of 30 pointers to int.

Answer (score 0):

Above declaration can be understood by the **Clockwise/Spiral** rule.

[image]

Following describes how to parse the declaration using the rule:

> 1) ***table*** is a function with unspecified arguments.
>
> 2) The ***table()*** function returns a **pointer**.
>
> 3) The **pointer** returned by *table()* function points to an array of **30** elements.
>
> 4) Each element is of type ***integer pointers*** i.e., each element is pointing to an integer.

More about the rule is well explained in this link : [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 0):

The identifier *table* is a function which returns a pointer to an array of 30 integer pointers. As a complement to learning the so called [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), you can use a site like http://cdecl.org/ to find out.

If I was able to rewrite the code I would split the declaration into a type declaration and a function declaration. That way it will be easier to understand the program text. Also I would call the result type *Table* and choose a more specific name for the function, which most likely returns a special kind of table, say a *Foo* table. If possible I would also avoid the empty parameter list and use the keyword *void* to specify that the function takes no parameters:

```
typedef int *(*Table)[30];

Table FooTable(void);
```